# Rest API using Symfony4

Tags: json, rest, symfony, symfony4

I have been creating REST API using symfony4,
I have installed FosRestBundle and I configured it to return object directly from the controller.

I want to return an object from the controller but I get the error

```
Warning: ReflectionObject::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given
```

MoviesController:

```
/**
 * @Rest\View()
 * @Route("/movies", name="get_movies")
 *
 */
public function getMovies()
{
    $movies = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository(Movie::class)
                    ->findAll();

    return $movies;

 }
```

fos_rest.yaml:

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
    view:
        formats: { json: true, xml: false, rss: false }
        view_response_listener: true
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 'json' }
```

framework.yaml

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    view: { annotations: false }
```

Comment: You've disabled the SensioFrameworkExtra annotation for the view and this is wrong. You have to enable it. try this :   view:   { annotations: true }

Comment: I have enabled it, but still not working.

Comment: Annotation system must be enabled indeed. Verify your annotation of view (maybe a typo ? You didnt paste the declaration). Last solution to me is to dump the result of this condition that does not act as expected in your case https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/56c6df11da36b6937b54675a9f6ce03239b72e15/EventListener/ViewResponseListener.php#L67

Answer (score 1):

I use FOSRest, but my controller looks like:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;   //
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;                       // <-- first import
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest; //

class TagController extends FOSRestController      // <-- extend
{
    /**
     * Retrieves a collection of Tag resource.
     *
     * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"details"})
     * @Rest\Get("/tag")                            // <-- rout
     */
    public function index(TagRepository $tagRepository): View // <-- use View
    {
        $data = $tagRepository->findAll();

        return View::create($data, Response::HTTP_OK);        // <-- how to return
    }
}
```